# Obtain IXMLDOMDocument2 from IXMLDocument

Tags: delphi, txmldocument

I am using Delphi 2010 with only the stock standard VCL libraries. The target system is win32.

If I have a reference to an IXMLDocument, how can I obtain an IXMLDOMDocument2 interface to the underlying object that IXMLDocument wraps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function GetXMLDOMDocument2(const XMLDocument: IXMLDocument): IXMLDOMDocument2;
begin
  Result := (XMLDocument.DOMDocument as IXMLDOMNodeRef).GetXMLDOMNode as IXMLDOMDocument2;
end;
```